# How do you write 縮めて in IPA?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you write 縮めて in IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet)?

Answer (score 5):

It's pronounced [[c̟ɕiʑimete]], although in careful speech it would probably be [[c̟ɕiɟʑimete]]―there's no contrast between [[ʑi]] and [[ɟʑi]] in Modern Japanese, so the word will be understood either way.

For the pronunciation of ち and ぢ, see section 4.3 "Affricates" in Vance's *The Sounds of Japanese* (2008), starting on page 82.  [Most of this section is available online at Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hos-XSzQ87AC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&ots=XGzpDvrtSH&sig=-HgtDwUGRSnLtLLeTsNwZvZexc8&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=i1KLU82UI83coASds4HgCg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ&f=false#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: You use [c]. Does this mean that the [chart on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Japanese) is incomplete/incorrect?

Comment: @Earthliŋ It's a lamino-alveopalatal stop, which doesn't have its own IPA symbol but is between [[c]] and [[t]].  To be precise, you can either write [[c̟]] indicating an advanced place of articulation, or [[t̠]] indicating a retracted place of articulation.  See Vance p.82.

Answer (score 3):

Writing IPA for Japanese is really quite simple in most cases.

Look up [IPA for Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Japanese) and use the sounds there to write your word.

> 縮めて
>   [tɕi(d)ʑimeteꜜ]

The `ꜜ` is a tone drop, although here on Japanese.SE we have a fantastic way of writing pitch for かな: ちぢめて【LHHH】. (Correct pitch due to @非回答者.)

Comment: The pitch is LHHH, not LHLL.  http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/search/index/sortprefix:accent/narabi1:kata_asc/narabi2:accent_asc/narabi3:mola_asc/yure:visible/curve:invisible/details:visible/limit:20/word:%E7%B8%AE%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B

Comment: @非回答者 Oh, thank you (also for the reference!). Sometimes I confuse myself where the downstep is supposed to be.